# how to return json error msg in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I would like to return a json errormessage but at the moment in fiddler I cannot see this in the json panel:

```
string error = "An error just happened";
JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult
{
     Data = error,
     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, jsonResult.Data);
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 69):

A few points:

If all you're looking to do is return an error response containing a simple error message, Web API provides a `CreateErrorResponse` method for that.  So you can simply do:

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                                   "An error just happened");
```

This will result in the following HTTP response (other headers omitted for brevity):

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 36

{"Message":"An error just happened"}
```

If you want to return a custom object instead, then you use `Request.CreateResponse` like you were doing, but don't use the MVC `JsonResult`.  Instead, just pass your object directly to `CreateResponse`:

```
var myError = new
{
    Data = "An error just happened",
    OtherDetails = "foo bar baz"
};

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, myError);
```

Now, say you are doing this but you're not getting JSON back from the server.  It is important to realize that Web API normally uses content type negotiation to determine what format to use when sending the response back.  That means, it looks at the `Accept` header that was sent by the client with the request.  If the `Accept` header contains `application/xml`, for example, then Web API will return XML.  If the header contains `application/json` then it will return JSON.  So, you should check that your client is sending the correct `Accept` header.

That said, there are ways to force Web API to always return data in a specific format if that is what you really want.  You can do this at the method level by using a different overload of `CreateResponse` which also specifies the content type:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, myError, 
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Alternatively, you can remove the XML formatter from the configuration altogether in your `WebApiConfig` file:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

This will force Web API to always use JSON regardless of what the client asks for.

Comment: This: new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"). Thanks a lot. The exact missing piece I was looking for.

Comment: This doesn't compile for me. I get.. "cannot convert from '<anonymous type: string errors>' to 'string'"

Comment: @IanWarburton It seems you are using Request.CreateErrorResponse instead of Request.CreateResponse method.

Comment: Request.CreateResponse doesn't work in .net 6 api?

Answer (score 10):

you can return JSON like below,

```
 return Request.CreateResponse<ResponseApiModel>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
```

I recommend to use [IHttpActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758615/why-should-i-use-ihttpactionresult-instead-of-httpresponsemessage) on your method return type instead HttpResponseMessage, if your api's method return type is IHttpActionResult.  you can return like;

```
 return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response);
```

you can check also that link about best practice of [error returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732644/best-practice-to-return-errors-in-asp-net-web-api) Especially @Daniel Little's answer is really useful.

I know the answer added to late but maybe stand someone in good stead.

Comment: with  'Content', the message returned is not in json format.

Answer (score 1):

JsonResult is a MVC concept.  It does not work in Web API.  One way to explicitly return json content is to use the class I created in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20504951/6819

Answer (score 0):

Add 
**config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);** 
line in your WebApiConfig file

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you or others.

define your custom ApiController

```
public abstract class ApiController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    protected internal virtual BadRequestErrorMessageResult BadRequest(object message)
    {
        return new BadRequestErrorMessageResult(message);
    }
}
```

define custom message result class

```
public class BadRequestErrorMessageResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly object _message;

    public BadRequestErrorMessageResult(object message)
    {
        _message = message;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<object>(_message, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json")
        };
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

use your custom response method

```
 // GET api/<controller>
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        return BadRequest(new
        {
            Succeeded = false,
            Message = "An error occurred during processing, please contact the administrator!"
        });
    }
```

response data with custom header error status code

```
{"Succeeded":false,"Message":"An error occurred during processing, please contact the administrator!"}
```

Answer (score -6):

You can directly set the status code of the current HTTP response through Response property

```
Response.StatusCod = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return Json(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```